# jquery wont fire in asp.net using telerik controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a simple page that I need to open the print dialog on once the page has completed loading and I was going to achieve this using jquery, however I don't seem to be able to get my jquery to run.

I have followed the guide on [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-using-jquery.html), as we are using their controls and for simplicity I'd like to not have to introduce more than one version of jQuery unless its absolutely neccessary which I don't think it is.

I have tried a few of the methods listed there and none seem to work, replacing the jquery with just a normal JS alert works though.

This is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Print.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.Modules.Plan.Print"
    Theme="Plan" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Print Your plan</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Document is ready");
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager" >
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <div>
        <div id="divInstrumentTitle" runat="server" class="InstrumentTitle">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblInstrumentTitle" CssClass="InstrumentTitle" /></div>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlEplan" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas as to whats going on here?

Comment: Are you sure what jquery-library.js was attached? I dont see '<script type="text/javascript" src="..'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your scripts below the RadScriptManager, so move them out of the head into the body, at the end of the form, to test to see if that makes a difference.